# simple script to check if a webpage has been updated

Tags: bash, web, scrape

There is some information that I am waiting for on a website. I do not wish to check it every hour. I want a script that will do this for me and notify me if this website has been updated with the keyword that I am looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a basic bash script for checking if the webpage [www.nba.com](http://www.nba.com) contains the keyword `Basketball`. The script will output `www.nba.com updated!` if the keyword is found, if the keyword isn't found the script waits 10 minutes and checks again.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ];
do
    count=`curl -s "www.nba.com" | grep -c "Basketball"`

    if [ "$count" != "0" ]
    then
       echo "www.nba.com updated!"
       exit 0   
    fi
    sleep 600   
done
```

We don't want the site or the keyword hard-coded into the script, we can make these arguments with the following changes.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ];
do
    count=`curl -s "$1" | grep -c "$2"`

    if [ "$count" != "0" ]
    then
       echo "$1 updated!"
       exit 0
    fi
    sleep 600
done
```

Now to run the script we would type `./testscript.sh www.nba.com Basketball`. We could change the `echo` command to have the script send an email or any other preferred way of notification. *Note we should check that arguments are valid.*

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

go and configure a google alert..

You can also crawl the website and search for the keyword you are interested in.

Comment: Yes, but I want to search a specific page.

Comment: write a script that periodically downloads the content from that page and checks if the word you are interested in exists.. You can make some optimizations like: don't check if page hasn't been updated since you last checked etc..